# JavaScript - SetInterval doesn't function properly

Tags: javascript

I got this piece of script (runned locally):

```
<script>

last = 0;

function uploadnew(){

var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
if(randomnumber != last){
    document.forms['f'+randomnumber].submit();
} else { uploadnew(); }

}

setInterval (uploadnew(), 1000*60*5);

</script>
```

But it seems that setInterval is not working / send form function doesn't work...

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: If you submit a form to the same window, it will load a new page and stop the interval

Comment: yeap, I know. I'm loading it into iframe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to call [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) without parenthesis on your function, like this:

```
setInterval(uploadnew, 1000*60*5);
```

Using parenthesis you're calling it *immediately* and assigning the *result* (`undefined`) to be run on an interval, instead don't use parenthesis to pass the function itself, not the *result* of the function.

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove the `()` after `uploadnew` within the setInterval call:

```
setInterval (uploadnew, 1000*60*5);
```

In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects which can be passed to other functions. In this example, you want to pass the function itself to setInterval, not call it first and then pass its return value.

Using `setInterval ("uploadnew()", 1000*60*5);` is not recommended because it is a "hidden" form of eval. [Eval is evil and you shouldn't use it if you don't have to.](https://ericlippert.com/2003/11/01/eval-is-evil-part-one/)

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass a reference to the function instead of calling it.

This:

```
setInterval (uploadnew(), 1000*60*5);
```

should be:

```
setInterval (uploadnew, 1000*60*5);
```

If you were to call it as you were, you would need to have `uploadnew()` *return* a function to be passed to `setInterval`.

```
function uploadnew() {
    return function(){
        var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
        if(randomnumber != last) {
            document.forms['f'+randomnumber].submit();
        } else { uploadnew()(); }
    }
}
```

Note the change to the recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
setTimeout ( expression, timeout );
```